# It's possible create a new column in query result based in a list of ids?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the follow query

```
SELECT * FROM cellphones;
```

this query return something like this:

```
 cellphone_id  | cellphone_name    |  width  |  height
   232        |   Motorola     |  1920   |   1080  
   434        |   Samsung      |  720    |   1280 
   342        |   Apple        |  1440   |   2560
```

I would like that pass in my query a list of cellphone (e.g: cellphone = 232,342)
and this query add a new column named 'isFavorite' and set as TRUE value only the cellphones that contain in list that I pass in query.

NOTE: I don't want create/update anything my table, I would like return only it in my query result.

I do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cellphones
SET isFavorite=1 
WHERE cellphone_id IN (232,342)
```

and the result should be like this:

```
 cellphone_id  | cellphone_name  |  width  |  height | isFavorite
   232         |   Motorola      |  1920   |   1080  |    1
   434         |   Samsung       |  720    |   1280  |    0
   342         |   Apple         |  1440   |   2560  |    1
```

I tried do it, but not work:

```
SELECT * FROM cellphones
SET isFavorite=1 
WHERE cellphone_id IN (232,342)
```

Could you please help to build this query?

thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a case when  .. end

```
SELECT cellphones.*, case when cellphone_id IN (232,342) then 1 else 0  end  isFavorite
FROM cellphones
```